# How do I solve the "Between Worlds" Android puzzle game?

Tags: logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle

I've been struggling for a while with the [Between Worlds](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.BitShiftInteractive.Games.BetweenWorlds) Android game, and have not yet solved it. I've only noticed a couple vague properties that hold in localized cases.

[image]

To operate the puzzle, select the square, pentagon, or hexagon and move the lever. The spheres and rings on the right will move by some unknown conditions.

I would provide a summary of what I've done, but every example has at least two counterexamples. The only consistent pattern I've noticed is that, when a pair of pieces are in alignment, selecting the button counterclockwise of the circle that's in alignment doesn't move it out of place - but it doesn't hold in all cases, and I'm uncertain as to why.

What is the logical pattern behind this puzzle? How do I solve it?

Comment: Its not an unknown condition. The shapes always move to a fixed location. Press Hexagon+Lever 2x and you see the the small blue ring is back at the same location. If the blue ring is near the green ring it wont move when you use the square or pentagon.

Comment: @Teun There are other conditions in there changing the distances pieces move. You've found one such (potential - I have a counterexample) condition, but that's not enough to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Are you only looking for the solution, or a master pattern?

Comment: @Dennis I would prefer both, but would also appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game *is* possible.  I have completed it.

As you have guessed, the aim of the game is to assemble each dot with the 2 matching rings.

Hint 1

> Sorry, I cannot explain exactly how the pieces moves.  I haven't figures everything out.  But some general patterns were enough to solve it.  Don't loose your time working out every rule.

Hint 2

> One of the positive reviews on the Android store speaks about *lateral thinking* and *thinking outside of the box*.  Have you done that?

Hint 3

> If, without being instructed to do so, you 1. select a color, 2. press the lever, 3. wait, and repeat that over and over, then you are locked inside of your own rules.

Spoiler 1

> You *can* press 2 buttons at the same time.

Spoiler 2

> Press a color, press the lever, and before the lever moves back, press and hold another color.

Final spoiler

> When you start the game, activate blue 2 times to get to that recuring position where the 3 small circles overlap the large circles.  From there, activate red 3 times in a  row.  Then, do a combined green + blue activation: press green, press the lever and quickly press and hold blue.

Comment: Well, there's an interesting solution. I'm curious, how did you find it/how does it work?

Comment: He probably tried it.

Comment: I tried to understand the movement rules.  I tried and recorded many movements along with the results.  The blue ring always eluded me.  I ended up trying **all** movements from **all** positions.  And there was not solution.  That is then that I started searching for alternate moves.  When I got that I could work out enough of the working to convert one of my near-solutions to an actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this from memory, so some of the smaller details may not be correct, and I haven't had the time to sit down and actually solve the puzzle, but the master pattern is:

The 3 large rings form a triangle, which is equivalent to the triangle that's formed between the green square, the red pentagon and the blue hexagon.

Pressing the blue triangle would move the shapes in it's relative position a quarter of a circle counter clockwise.  If the medium blue ring is not located on the green large ring, then the shapes in the relative positions of the pentagon and hexagon would move 4/5ths and 2/3rds of a circle, respectively.

A similar pattern applies when pressing the red pentagon - the shapes in it's relative position will move a fifth of a circle, and if the medium green ring is not on the large red ring then the the shapes in the relative positions of the square and hexagon would move 1/2 and 5/6ths of a circle, respectively.

Similarly, when pressing the blue hexagon would move the shapes in it's relative position a sixth of a circle, and if the medium red ring is not located on the large blue ring than the shapes in the relative positions of the square and pentagon would move 3/4 and 3/5ths of a circle, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Each small dot and small ring are paired and move according to their cooresponding shapes perimeter. (i.e. red dot-green circle move perimeter of square, blue dot-red circle =perimeter of pentagon, green dot blue circle= perimeter of hexagon.) Think like you are moving 'gears' on a clock. I still haven't figured out which one triggers all of them to move in sync after I set them up in position right before their final spot.