# How do I find more enigmatic, no-clues-given puzzles?

Tags: puzzle-identification, enigmatic-puzzle

Most of my awareness of puzzles and puzzle games has come from a decade of haphazardly stumbling around the internet. There's a flavor/genre that I particularly enjoy, but I haven't had much luck finding more of them - or even nailing down to correct terms to find them. Lo and behold, I finally stumbled across [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/how-do-i-solve-the-between-worlds-android-puzzle-game), and it inspired me to ask you fine puzzlers for help.

I enjoy puzzles that are enigmatic - where you're presented with zero hints or guidance, and all progress and information is hard-won through deduction / trial and error. Here are a few great examples:

- [The Control Panel](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/214420)
- [Binary](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/542840)
- [ClickDragType Series](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/search/games/clickdragtype)

Unfortunately all I have are links to Newgrounds, which should immediately indicate how much I'm hurting for fresh specimens. The main problem I seem to be having is that the "Puzzle" category in any given source is very ambiguous - they lump in anything from bejeweled to jigsaws to quiz games, and after years of casual searching I'm tired of filtering through hundreds of pages with no success.

Is there a specific name for this kind of game? Are there any sites or sources that would help me find more? I'm completely in the dark here - any help or insight is much appreciated.

Comment: Lists aren't on topic on Stack Exchange sites, so as to your PS, no, that's not in the spirit of the site.  (The list wouldn't necessarily have staying power, and isn't something the site is necessarily built to handle well anyway.)  The main part of your question - 'Is there a specific name for this kind of game' - seems on topic to me.

Comment: I know a few games like this, if you are interested. Antichamber, Kairo, Q.U.B.E., Fez, Don't starve.

Comment: Cicada 3301....

Comment: You would probably enjoy the stanislaw lem google doodle which is a puzzle about communication with an alien, not terribly difficult but a nice tribute. http://www.google.com/logos/lem/

Comment: I remember a great one from 1998: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Merlin_Mystery Similar puzzles are at http://www.treasureclub.net/publichunts/index.html

Answer (score 6):

The MIT mystery hunt has full archives of puzzles online.

[MIT Mystery hunt](http://www.mit.edu/~puzzle/)

This is an annual, real-world event, where the winners from last year write all the puzzles for the event.

Classic online puzzles are the [TIM TANG TEST](http://www.timtang.com/ttt/) and Not Pr0n, which I think is gone although it may be archived somewhere.

Machinarium (you can find it on Steam and Amanita Design's website) is a BEAUTIFUL puzzle point and click.

Comment: Oh, I also made an enigmatic point and click puzzler a couple years ago:
[Cairn](http://www.kongregate.com/games/aampere/cairn) : D

Answer (score 5):

There is a class of puzzle which typically has the enigmatic nature that you describe, although it's not quite the same as the online games you link: the [puzzle hunt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puzzlehunt). I have also heard these referred to as "*CiSRA-style puzzles*", and that's the search term I used to find that Wikipedia page.